# Navbar mudando de cor ao scroll

Tags: html, css

tentei fazer um navbar que no inicio da page fica transparente e ao rolar o scrool ele mude o fundo do nav para preto(ex).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo:

```css
*{
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 1000px;
 background-image: url(../6.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
}
.navbar{
 width: 100%;
 padding: 20px;
 position: fixed;
 top:0px;
 text-align: center;
 transition: .5s;
}
.navbar ul li{
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 50px;
 color: white;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 10px;
} 
.navbar ul li:hover{
 background: orange;
}
.box{
 width: 80%;
 height: 2000px;
 background: green;
 margin: 20px auto;
 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Documento sem título</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

 <div class="header">
 <div class="navbar">
  <ul>
   <li>Home</li>
   <li>Loja</li>
   <li>Contato</li>
   <li>Faq</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
<div class="box">
  </div>

  
  <script>
  var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
  window.scroll=function(){
   if(window.pageYOffset>100){
    
    nav.style.background = "#007bff";
    
   }
   else{
    nav.style.background = "transparent";
   }
  }
  </script>
  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Inclua detalhes sobre o que você tentou e exatamente o que você está tentando fazer. Recomendo um [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: tentei fazer um navbar que no inicio da page fica transparente e ao rolar o scrool ele mude o fundo do nav para preto(ex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema foi que vc nao colocou o evento no scroll

```
var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
            if(window.pageYOffset>100){

                nav.style.background = "#007bff";

            }
            else{
                nav.style.background = "transparent";
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
document.body.onscroll = () => { //... função igual aqui ... }
```

E faltou o ID no navbar

```
<div class="navbar" id="nav">
```

Comment: no caso eu teria q por a partir do var nav dentro do document.body.onscroll?

Comment: em vez de usar "window.scroll=function(){ " use 
"document.body.onscroll = () => {"

Comment: eu fiz igualzin e não foi

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XFDKZ5Tr
Aqui rodou corretamente, navbar em azul, e fica branco quando está no topo, o problema é que a cor da letra também é branca, junto com o fundo que é branco

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FN4R3943AZXM